# Auto Fill but changing only certain cells

Tags: google-sheets-query

I am trying to make a QR code attendance system and try to organize it so I can see what student comes on what day. I am trying to auto fill everything so I don't have to type everything for every month because I want to have it for the whole year. However every time I drag it !A1:B30 keeps changing but I only need  D1 to change to the next cell. If its possible I would appreciate it.

=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:B30,"Select * where A contains date '"&text(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")

[image: Trying to see what students come on what day]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.